# preventDefault() in AJAX doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't `event.preventDefault();` work in this AJAX-setting?

```
$( "#formID" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'data': 'anything' },
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function( json ) {
        if (!json.result) { 
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

On submitting a form I want to check via Ajax if a condition is true or false.
Depending on that the submit should be prevented (if result of the AJAX call is false).

Is this possible?

Comment: It's **asynchronous**, by the time the callback executes, it's way too late to start preventing anything.

Comment: since ajax is asynchronous the form will get submitted before the ajax is completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since ajax is asynchronous the form will get submitted before the ajax is completed

```
$("#formID").submit(function (event) {
    //prevent the form submit by default
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            'data': 'anything'
        },
        dataType: "json"
    })
        .done(function (json) {
        if (json.result) {
            //if ajax is success submit the form
            form.submit()
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `return false;` to prevent default submit. If you want to wait data return use `async: false`

```
$( "#formID" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'data': 'anything' },
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    })
    .done(function( json ) {
        if (!json.result) { 
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault` will prevent any specified event prior to form submission. In your case, you call preventDefault inside callback function of Ajax call, which is an asynchronous call where your form would be submitted before the callback function executes. So it doesn't make any sense where you placed it.

Place it out of Ajax call (prior to ajax call) as follows,

```
$( "#formID" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'data': 'anything' },
        dataType: "json"
    })
.
.
```

and call the form submit inside ajax callback method if your result is satisfied.

```
.done(function( json ) {
        if (json.result) { 
            // Do form submit here.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, it's the same way as Arun Johnny does in another answer.. :)